# Android ObjectInputStream readObject throws IllegalAccessException

Tags: java, android, exception, serialization, objectinputstream

I am trying to write a Serialized Object in my onPause method into a file so that I can read it again from the file when I start the app another time and need the previous data.

This is where i save the Object

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fout = openFileOutput(logFileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream fw = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
    fw.writeObject(obj);
    Log.d("obj", "added");
    fw.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("obj", "not added");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return;
```

I can see the "added" message and this means that the Object has been saved in the file.

Here is where i try to read the saved object:

```
try {
    FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(logFileName);
    ObjectInputStream fread = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
    Object res = fread.readObject();
    Log.d("obj", "readed successfully");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I get this :

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: android.view.View; IllegalAccessException
```

on the line calling "fread.readObject()". I would thank you if you could please tell me why is it throwing the following Exception.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try calling : `fw.flush()` before `fw.close()`

Comment: @Fouad Still no change!